# Send xml from vb.net to php file

Tags: php, xml, vb.net, http-post

How to send xml file from vb.net that can be caught using `$HTTP_ROW_POST` in PHP?

My script is:

```
Public Function PHP(ByVal url As String, ByVal method As String, ByVal data As String)

    Try

        Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Method = method
        Dim postData = data
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
        Return (responseFromServer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim error1 As String = ErrorToString()
        If error1 = "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." Then
            MsgBox("ERROR! Must have HTTP:// before the URL.")
        Else
            MsgBox(error1)
        End If
        Return ("ERROR")
    End Try
End Function
```

But I can not capture it in the PHP file using `$HTTP_ROW_POST`.

Comment: Also related: [HTML data sent through HttpWebRequest in vb.net is empty when it gets to php's $_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5860450/367456)

Answer (score 4):

Don't set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as it would imply `key=value` pairs sent in the request body. Set it to `application/xml` because that is what you're sending.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim resp As String = PHP("http://localhost/test.php", "POST", "<xml>test</xml")
        System.Console.WriteLine(resp)
    End Sub

    Public Function PHP(ByVal url As String, ByVal method As String, ByVal data As String)
        Try
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
            Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
            request.Method = method
            request.ContentType = "application/xml"
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim responseFromServer As String = (New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd()

            response.Close()
            Return (responseFromServer)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim error1 As String = ErrorToString()
            If error1 = "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." Then
                MsgBox("ERROR! Must have HTTP:// before the URL.")
            Else
                MsgBox(error1)
            End If
            Return ("ERROR")
        End Try
    End Function

End Module
```

works well with the php server script

```
<?php
$c = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo 'got: ', $c;
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/wrappers.php.php